# Python Mysql select same value on diffrent table

Tags: python, mysql

I'm working with mysql in Python. I have two tables.
The columns of the tables are the same.
I want the 'name' columns to be written to another table when they match other.

Mysql and python

```
table1

JOHN       | 22

PETER      | 13

MARK       | 26


table2

JOHN       | 22

CHRIS      | 44

THOR       | 56
```

table 3 should be:

```
JOHN       | 22
```

Comment: You want the inner join of the two tables

Comment: show your expected  result  .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that what you want to do ?

```sql
INSERT INTO table3(name,id)
SELECT t1.name, t1.id
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.id = t1.id;
```

Be careful about duplicate rows.

Answer (score 0):

you can select the matching name using a inner join

```
select name 
from table1 
inner join  table2 ON table1.name  = table2.name
```

and you can populate  a new table using insert select

```
insert into new_table (name)
select name 
from table1 
inner join  table2 ON table1.name  = table2.name
```